# getMacAddress() is returning null

Tags: android, android-wifi

This is the code snippet that I use

```
public static String getMACAddressOfDevice(Context context){
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        String macAddress = wifiInfo.getMacAddress();
        return macAddress;
    }
```

sometime it returns null.I don't understand why !
Can anybody explain me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When *wifi* is switched off , some android device returns null.

It's in current design.

If the device *doesn't have wifi hardware* , then this approach doesn't work.

There are some other alternatives for unique identification of devices

**IMEI:**

```
TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
String m_deviceId = TelephonyMgr.getDeviceId();
```

*Drawbacks:*

It is sim card dependent so

- If there is no sim card then we're doomed
- If there is dual sim then we're dommed

**Bluetooth address:**

```
BluetoothAdapter m_BluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); 
   String m_bluetoothAdd = m_BluetoothAdapter.getAddress();
```

*Drawbacks:*

- if there is no bluetooth hardware we're doomed.
- In future in some new devices we mightn't able to read it if its off.

**Serial:**

We can read the hardware serial number.It can be seen in the device settings.

```
 Build.SERIAL
```

*Drawbacks:*

- If the device doesn't have *telephony*,this can't be used.There are some *wifi-only* devices are available in market.

**Android_ID:**

You can try using the *ANDROID_ID* its good for unique identification of the devices since its not dependent on any hardware *IMEI*

```
String m_androidId = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

*Drawbacks:*

- If OS version is upgraded then it may change
- If device is rooted it gets changed
- No guarantee that the device_id is unique there are some reports some manufacturers are having duplicate device_id

**Suggestion:**

The safest bet is to use ***Android_ID*** because it's not dependent on availability of any hardware

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31581290/730807)